# Python function that produces both generator and aggregate results

Tags: python, generator

What is the Pythonic way to make a generator that also produces aggregate results? In meta code, something like this (but not for real, as my Python version does not support mixing yield and return):

```
def produce():
    total = 0
    for item in find_all():
        total += 1
        yield item

    return total
```

As I see it, I could:

1. Not make `produce()` a generator, but pass it a callback function to call on every `item`.
2. With every `yield`, also `yield` the aggregate results up until now. I'd rather not calculate the intermediate results with every yield, only when finishing.
3. Send a `dict` as argument to `produce()` that will be populated with the aggregate results.
4. Use a global to store aggregate results.

All of them don't seem very attractive...

NB. `total` is a simple example, my actual code requires complex aggregations. And I need intermediate results before `produce()` finishes, hence a generator.

Comment: So total is just the equivalent of the length of the iterable returned by `find_all`? For that you could just use `enumerate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you shouldn't use a generator but an iterator.

```
def findall():  # no idea what your "find_all" does so I use this instead. :-)
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

class Produce(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._it = iterable
        self.total = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.total += 1
        return next(self._it)

    next = __next__  # only necessary for python2 compatibility
```

Maybe better to see this with an example:

```
>>> it = Produce(findall())
>>> it.total
0
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
2
>>> it.total
2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to count stuff, for example

```
i=0
for i,v in enumerate(range(10), 1 ):
    print(v)
print("total",i)
```

(notice the start value of the enumerate)

for more complex stuff, you can use the same principle, make produce a generator that yield both values and ignore one in the iteration and use it later when finished.

other alternative is passing a modifiable object, for example

```
def produce(mem):
    t=0
    for x in range(10):
        t+=1
        yield x
    mem.append(t)

aggregate=[]
for x in produce(aggregate):
    print(x)
print("total",aggregate[0])
```

in either case the result is the same for this example

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
total 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Why not:

```
def produce():
   total = 0
   for item in find_all():
       total += 1
       yield item

    yield total
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of this! It could work, but then the caller would have to figure out whether it got an `item` object or a `total` object. Hmm.